# How to convert a known function to a neural network

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

Suppose I have a known function, for **example**:

```
def func(x):
    m = np.mean(x)
    if m > 1: 
       return 1
    else:
       return 0
```

Are there any algorithms to convert this into a neural network?

A naive way would be:

- use `func` to generate training set
- train the NN using the training set

But this will be slow and the trained NN will probably be inaccurate. Are there better ways to "copy" a known function?

As the questions suggests, I am not asking about the about trivial **example** function, I am asking about a **general** known function!

Comment: Why is it necessary to do something like this? If you know the function, why not use it directly?

Comment: it can be really useful, but I am not gonna talk about it here to raise unnecessary debates.  of course you can think of it as "unnecessary", but that doesn't change the fact that the above is a valid academic question

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is possible to translate the function into a neural network without training because you know the function and don't need to learn the weights.

If you know the number of elements in x, then the mean can be a single layer network with the number of elements in x as an input and no output. The weights of the network are just 1/len(x), and you can set the bias to 0.
Then you can build your own activation function which returns 1 if the output is superior to 1, 0 else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: note that I highlighted **example**, the function I gave is just an example! and it is so easy to just manually set the paramerter, what i am asking is how to do it generally!

Comment: in that case I don't think it's possible to help you further. But your suggested method is probably best: you can generate samples using the deterministic function and use those to train a NN. The most difficult part will be to find the appropriate architecture and compexity